# Inheritance in Python models

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance, django-models

Having a little misunderstanding with the inheritance in Python.
I have one parent class:

```
class BaseClass(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

  name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'name')
    )
  surname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'surname')
    )    
   class Meta:
      abstract = True

   def __str__(self):
        
       
       if self.name:
            return self.name
       elif self.email:
            return self.email
       else:
            return self.phone
```

And I would like to use these all data in child class named SecondClass, but I dont know what I must to insert in body section of this class:

```
class SecondClass(BaseClass):
```

Comment: If you don't want to add anything, just put `pass`.

Comment: `pass`, a docstring or (if you follow standard lib's stubs) `...` are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good resource for this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

If you don't need to add anything else to the child class, then you can just do

```
class SecondClass(BaseClass):
    pass
```